# Recreate FontAwesome Spinner

Tags: css, font-awesome

In my project some users can't see FontAwesome icons, but I can see them from my end.

I have used font-awesome icons like this :

```
<i class="fa fa-cog">
```

Since, some users can't see them, I have transitioned above code to using

```
<span class"faCog"></span>

.faCog {
  &:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: '\f013';
  }
}
```

My problem now is that I want the cog to spin but I can't seem to get it to work. Before I was just able to do

```
<i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw">
```

I tried adding this to my faCog class but no dice

```
&:after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

My goal is to have a spinning cog icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use animation for this. Check this out : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

```css
.faCog.spin:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f013';
  display: inline-block;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 5000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear; 
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<span class="faCog spin"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a spinning animation to make this work.

```css
.faCog {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
    animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
}
.faCog:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: '\f013';
  }

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<p>
  <strong>Normal Icon</strong>
  <br/>
  <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Custom Icon</strong>
  <br/>
  <span class="faCog"></span>
</p>
```